# Keyboard doesn't show when clicking into a MultiAutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am having the problem that the soft keyboard doesn't come up when clicking into the `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`. When I first click into another `EditText` and then change to the `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`, I can enter text but not when I click into it directly.

I don't use anything like requestFocus or onClick handlers.

Here is the XML:

```
<MultiAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/thingTags"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:hint="@string/hint_tags"
    android:inputType="textShortMessage"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the `android:textIsSelectable="true"` is the culprit. If I remove that, it works again.